# Deserialize returns null key and null value (count is correct)

Tags: c#

I am experimenting with C# serialization, and had to serialize a Dictionary, as it isn't serializable I used an XML string, which then gets deserialized (example taken from https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adam/2010/09/10/how-to-serialize-a-dictionary-or-hashtable-in-c/)

DictionaryDataItem class:

```
[Serializable]
public class DictionaryDataItem
{
    public string Key;

    public string Value;

    public DictionaryDataItem(string key, string value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;

    }

    public DictionaryDataItem()
    {
        Key = "";
        Value = "";
    }
}
```

Serialization code:

```
[WebMethod]
public string ListarPaises()
{
    List<DictionaryDataItem> Paises = new List<DictionaryDataItem>();

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DictionaryDataItem>));
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
    ns.Add("", "");
    try
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> diccionario = FabricaLogica.getLogicaGeneral().ListarPaises();

        foreach (string key in diccionario.Keys)
        {
            Paises.Add(new DictionaryDataItem(key, diccionario[key]));
        }

        serializer.Serialize(sw, Paises, ns);
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ThrowSoapException(ex);
    }
    return sw.ToString();
}
```

The serialization works and it returns the following string as xml:

```xml
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ArrayOfDictionaryDataItem>
    <DictionaryDataItem>
        <Key>ARG</Key>
        <Value>ARGENTINA</Value>
    </DictionaryDataItem>
    <DictionaryDataItem>
        <Key>BRA</Key>
        <Value>BRASIL</Value>
    </DictionaryDataItem>
    <DictionaryDataItem>
        <Key>URU</Key>
        <Value>URUGUAY</Value>
    </DictionaryDataItem>
</ArrayOfDictionaryDataItem>
</string>
```

And then, my deserialization code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Paises = new Dictionary<string, string>();

string RawData = new WebService.WebService().ListarPaises();

XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DictionaryDataItem>));
StringReader sr = new StringReader(RawData);
List<DictionaryDataItem> templist = (List<DictionaryDataItem>)xs.Deserialize(sr);

foreach (DictionaryDataItem di in templist)
{
    Paises.Add(di.Key, di.Value);
}

return Paises;
```

I can see that `templist` has 3 items, but both key and value for all of the items is null.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Where do you set `xmlelement` and `xmlarray`?

Comment: @T.S. hmm I have no idea... let me add the DictionaryDataItem class and the serialization code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you learning about XML serialization? The article you're using as a guide is from 2010 and the industry has changed a lot since then: thesedays most serialization is done to JSON (which is much more space-efficient than XML) or to a binary format like protobufs.

Comment: You can serialize `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` to XML using `DataContractSerializer`. The stock `XmlSerializer` does not support `IDictionary` because the dev team ran out of time back in 2001 for .NET Framework 1.1. See here: https://theburningmonk.com/2010/05/net-tips-xml-serialize-or-deserialize-dictionary-in-csharp/

Comment: @Dai it's a requirement for this a project in a class I'm taking... I saw lots of ways using json, I'm actually not a fan of xml, but had to do it with XML.

Comment: Properties `Key` and `Value` would be `XmlElement`. Collection of `DictionaryDataItem` would be `XmlArray`. In other words, you would need 2 classes - one is root element with collection and another ... you already have

Comment: @T.S. mind helping me with that other needed class? really lost here.

Comment: There is MSDN for it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute?view=netframework-4.7.2 The concept is same pattern as always - item/itemCollection

Comment: You can use a SortedDictionary instead of a Dictionary if you want to make it easier, as it's serializable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=netframework-4.7.2 It works in the same way as a Dictionary for the most part.

Comment: @0liveradam8 no, that doesn't work as it implements IDictionary, which is not serializable: `The type System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] is not supported because it implements IDictionary.`